# Is it possible to use the ViewBag or Model of a View in the parent Layout?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .Net Core 2.1 website and basically I'm trying to access data in my shared layout which is available in the child views. I could get what I need either from something from the ViewBag or from the View model in the view - is there a way to reference it somehow?

If not any ideas what might be the best approach to grab the data in my layout? I've had a look at ViewComponents eg https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/01/02/goodbye-child-actions-hello-view-components.aspx but it seems like overkill for just grabbing something like a string or model. Unfortunately I can't use session data to pass values.

Many thanks and sorry if it's a noob question (I am one with .net core!).

Answer (score 0):

## Passing objects

For passing objects you can use either **ViewBag** or **ViewData**. Both work in similar fashion using `ViewDataDictionary` beneath, this means you can use them interchangeably.

To set the value:

```
ViewBag.HelloWorld = "Hello world!";
ViewData["HelloWorld"] = "Hello world!";
```

To consume the value in view:

```
@ViewBag.HelloWorld
@ViewData["HelloWorld"]
```

`ViewDataDictionary` can be populated and consumed inside both controllers and views.

### Differences to using ViewBag and ViewData:

**ViewBag** is derived from `DynamicViewData` and requires no casting for usage, but won't let you set key with spaces in it.

**ViewData** is derived from `ViewDataDictionary` and offers useful dictionary properties and functions. Also keys can contain spaces. Requires type casting or will default to `ToString()`.

---

## Passing HTML blocks

You can also pass around blocks of HTML, inside layout you can render section

```
@RenderSection("Header", required: false)
```

In individual views you can then inject into this section

```
@section Header {
    <strong>I sit in the existing header!</strong>
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't say if a layout can use a view object

Comment: ViewDataDictionary is available for the entirety of the request, it means also for current layout.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is yes - you can use the ViewBag and ViewData object of a child view in the parent shared layout.